# Axial or centrifugal fan for short run out of kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, ventilation, ducts, fans

I'm researching replacements for a broken extractor fan in my kitchen. It is wall mounted and runs through the wall straight outside, no long ducting involved.

The current (broken) fan is the centrifugal design. My understanding these are best for long runs of ducting, and seem to be lower powered (lower volume of air removed per hour) compared to axial fans.

Another point to mention is that there is a shutter on the end of the ducting, on the outside (to prevent backdraft and bugs/dirt/debris getting in, I guess)

My question is, given I don't have a long duct to extract through, should I get an axial fan over centrifugal design. Axial fans seem to be more powerful, and the increased airflow seems good to clear out kitchen cooking odours, smoke, etc.

Comment: Axial fans have great "CFM ratings at no or very minimal backpressure" - they are not "more powerful" - a centrifugal blower will often outperform them in the real world, where you need enough pressure to open that flap/shutter, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, that was another consideration I forgot to mention - that the fan needs to be able to push air through the shutter.

Comment: If you get an axial one, be sure to provide fixed vanes after the blades to get some pressure out of it, or it won't blow outside almost any air.

Answer (score 1):

If not over a stove it may not matter much but if over a stove where it will pick up more grease and be harder to clean if centrifugal. The blades on an axial would be easier to clean and that is what I would use for ease of cleaning.

Comment: Thanks @Ed In my case, the fan isn't near the stove so cleaning shouldn't be too much of a factor.